# I want to implement sharepoint document search using C# api

Tags: c#, http, post, sharepoint, get

I want to search sharepoint document using C# api call.

I am trying below code:

```
 string URL = "http://server/_api/search/query?query_parameter=value&amp;query_parameter=value";

            System.Net.Http.HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string.Format("{0}:{1}", "XXXXX", "XXXXXX"))));
            using (client)
            {
                HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = await client.GetAsync(URL);
                HttpResponseMessage responsemMsgx = httpResponseMessage;
                if (responsemMsgx.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                }
            }
```

But,i am have a doubt regarding URL below:
string URL = "http://server/_api/search/query?query_parameter=value&query_parameter=value";

Please help me with the sharepoint server and constructing the URL.
My expected output is something like JSON .

Comment: `&amp;` is an XML-encoded ampersand and is extremely unusual to put that in a URL, where an ampersand is not a metacharacter. And then your link doesn't do that so I have no idea what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search documents, we can use the Search REST API below to achieve it.

```
/_api/search/query?querytext='IsDocument:True'
```

**C# example**:

```
string siteUrl = "http://sp2013/sites/team";
string searchQuery = "/_api/search/query?querytext='IsDocument:True'";//search all documents
var credential = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domainname");

HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler() { Credentials = credential };


HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json;odata=verbose");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("ContentType", "application/json;odata=verbose");

var result = client.GetAsync(siteUrl+searchQuery).Result;
var content = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
JObject jobj = JObject.Parse(content);
JArray jarr = (JArray)jobj["d"]["query"]["PrimaryQueryResult"]["RelevantResults"]["Table"]["Rows"]["results"];
foreach (JObject j in jarr)
{
    JArray results = (JArray)j["Cells"]["results"];
    var title = "";
    var path = "";
    foreach (JObject r in results)
    {
        if (r["Key"] != null) 
        {
            if (r["Key"].ToString() == "Title")
            {
                title = r["Value"].ToString();
            }
            if (r["Key"].ToString() == "Path")
            {
                path = r["Value"].ToString();
            }
        }                   
    }
    Console.WriteLine(title + "|" + path);
}
```

Comment: When i am running the program its showing error: the type or namespace name HttpClientHandler could not be found (are you missing a using directive) Please guide me as i am a beginner.

Comment: @MakeInIndiaInspire I recommend you first fix your query before you try to change your code (you can copy the search query into your browser or use an app like Fiddler)

Comment: @LZ_MSFT  Please correct me if I'm wrong but the usage of "result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;" makes me think that code might error (i.e. if you don't get a response) + I don't think it's good practice. Again, I might be wrong but if I'm not I might add that to your answer. I'd maybe add some comments in for the OP as they're new

Comment: Currently the JSON object is not getting populated with anything, because the URL might not work with credentials which i provide. Can you tell me how to create a test instance ,so that i can get a search result.

Comment: Please create a console application and use the code again, note: modify the "siteUrl", "username","password" and "domainname" in the code.
As Zain's comment, you can access the REST API in the browser to check if it works.

Comment: string siteUrl = "https://xxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/MOCTeams/BusinessDev/";
            string searchQuery = "Shared%20Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx?view=7&q=apiDemo";//search all documents
            var credential = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("emailidofsharepointlogin", "passwordofsharepoint", "company.com");

            HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler() { Credentials = credential };

apiDemo.docx is my document name created in murphyoil.com                                                                         I am getting 403 forbidden